# Nginx mp4 hotlink protection not working

Tags: nginx

I try to protect hotlink for mp4 files, but does not work for me.

This is the code I am using:

```
  location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css)$ {
  valid_referers none blocked http://188.226.192.56;
  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
  }

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  expires 1d;
}
```

Works fine for .jpg, .png, etc, but not for mp4. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  ipaddress;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
location /usr/share/nginx/html/video/ {
    # activate flv/mp4 parsing for pseudostreaming
    flv;
    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size     4M;
    mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
}    
    location ~ .mp4$ {
    gzip off;
    gzip_static off;
    mp4;
    limit_rate_after 10m;
    limit_rate 1m;
}   
client_max_body_size    80m;

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css)$ {
  valid_referers none blocked http://188.226.192.56;
  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
  }

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  expires 1d;
}  

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

Thank You!

Comment: Are your videos served out of `/usr/share/nginx/html/video/`?

Comment: Add protection  to `location ~ .mp4$`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have a separate `location ~ .mp4$` block in your configuration, which nginx uses when sending out the files. Therefore your other `location` block that prevents hot-linking isn't applied.

Easiest way to fix this is to include hot-linking prevention to the MP4 location block like this:

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
    valid_referers none blocked http://188.226.192.56;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
    gzip off;
    gzip_static off;
    mp4;
    limit_rate_after 10m;
    limit_rate 1m;
}
```

In addition, your `location /usr/share/nginx/html/video/` directive is most likely useless. Unless your videos are accessed using `http://example.com/usr/share/nginx/html/video/videofile.mp4` like URLs, the directive is never used. You should remove it. `location` directive always needs an URI (part after domain in URL) for matching.

Another problem in your configuration is that you use `root` directive inside `location` blocks. You should use `root` only in the `server` level, and then if you need to specify other paths for some URL locations, then use `alias` directive inside those locations.